# Recording audio from output on iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad, audio-recording

I have to make an application that takes a few sampled loops and mixes them. I was thinking about using AVAudioPlayer so I can play the main sample and create one for each new sfx I want to put in. The big problem I stepped into was recording, as far as I could see in the documentation and some sample code, you can only record from the mic, and I need to record directly from the output so that I get the full mix but no ambient sound.

Any help will be really apreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

cannot provide sample code but you would have to record each file at your own and then combine all together in one stream. I think there is no direct function to record the "system-audio"